# How to interact with Cassandra 2.0.9 through HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, database, cassandra

I currently have a Bottle server running + [Bottle Cassandra driver](https://github.com/jeffjirsa/bottle-cassandra-driver) working just fine to output tables into a browser, but I'm interested to interact with my d\b through a simple html running on Apache server instead (perhaps using JavaScript?).

I couldn't find exact examples online or among [the drivers page](http://planetcassandra.org/client-drivers-tools/). Could anyone elaborate please?

**If possible, an html file that somehow uses the python bottle driver would be a solution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Currently, there is no client side JavaScript driver for Cassandra.** 
According to the Cassandra support IRC channel creating such solution is risky and may expose your system to outside threats. In case of anyone having a specific question about Cassandra, feel free to log into the [**IRC chat room here.**](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#cassandra)
The right approach to solve my problem was either develop an API (server side) and having the browser communicating w/ it (client side).
Since such solution requires very long developing time (and my little project is temporary after all), I decided to stick to my bottle server and to implement more interactive content:

- When serving a specific page, bottle would query the database for the IDs in the system.
  `allIDs = cqlconnection.execute("SELECT id FROM myTable.datamsg;")`
- Then, iterate through the array, and add it to a drop down (select) html element 
   `output.append('<html>')
  output.append('<body>')
  output.append('<select name="IDs" ')
  output.append('onchange="location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">')
  output.append('<option value="">CHOOSE ID!</option>')
  for addline in allIDs:
       output.append('<option value="/'+addline.id+'">'+addline.id+'</option>')
  output.append('</select>')
  output.append('</body>')
  output.append('</html>')`
- Where output is: `output = []` and at the end:
   `return bottle.HTTPResponse(status=200, body=output)#json.dumps(output))`
  [image]